# Can I run cable through a junction box in a cabinet and then to the dishwasher?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, dishwasher

My electrical wire to my dishwasher comes up through a hole in the subfloor wired right to the dishwasher.  I wanted to replace it (too much to go into here, just know the subfloor got wet, and I really don't like the wire there sitting in water when something goes wrong.).  Can I rerun 14/2 NM Romex from the panel to the sink cabinet next to the dishwasher and then run wire from that new junction box to the dishwasher?  I don't think it should simply come through the floor like that.  Maybe it could 40+ years ago (maybe today too), but I want it moved.

I hate pulling the dishwasher out super far to check things.  I thought the electrical would be easier to troubleshoot in the future, if I took this opportunity to rewire it.  I would still have to pull the dishwasher out a little bit to look at the small junction box built into the dishwasher where you hardwire it.  I'm only talking about the main line from the main panel box.

There is no garbage disposal if it matters.
It is 15A, but of course I will double-check.

Comment: Are you simply asking whether you can put a junction box between the panel and the dishwasher's connection box? Sure. There's no issue with that. I'm not sure how it changes anything, though. You'll still have to run a cable around behind the dishwasher to get to the unit's junction box.

Comment: Is the breaker 15A? - if it's 20A you'll need 12/2

Comment: 15A.  The wire from the sink cabinet goes in through the side near the dishwasher junction box, not the back.  I can't get to the back as it is at the outside wall.

Comment: Am I right it probably shouldn't becoming up through that hole straight into the dishwasher?

Comment: Doesn't really matter. It's no different than any of the other cable run through framing in your house. Mine's the same way (from 1992).

Comment: Normally, wiring is run through walls or floors, then ends in a box that holds a switch, fixture, or outlet, so seeing it come out of the floor then enter the dishwasher may seem odd. However, the purpose of the box is to A) provide a mounting point for the device in question, and B) to contain any heat/sparks should something go wrong with the connections to the device. There is no explicit issue with bare cable behind the direct wired dishwasher so long as you ensure that the cable itself isn't crushed/pinched when the dishwasher is pushed into place under the cabinet. [Con't]

Comment: If you're worried about crushing/pinching the cable, then you would want to end the in-wall run in a box, then use an armored cable (with appropriate grommets at each end) to go from the box in the wall to the dishwasher's box. However, since the dishwasher is in place and working, it's likely that the wiring is just fine. That armored cable won't, however, protect it from standing water. For that, you'd want to run UF-B cable from the box to the dishwasher since it's approved for direct burial/wet locations.

Comment: Is it somehow bad to wire a three prong plug to the dishwasher and plug into my new outlet junction box in the adjacent cabinet?  Is that "unsafe" for some reason?

Comment: @Ecnerwal It was 20A, thanks.  There is a "20" on the breaker switch.